# express.Router() delete not found

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I'm creating an restAPI and I'm not getting the express.Router () delete method to work

I'm looking for answers but all the answers I find are in line with what I did.

Only the delete method does not work, the others are OK.

**Routes file:**

```
const express = require('express')
const CustumerController = require('../controllers/CustumerController')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/customers', CustumerController.index)
router.get('/customers/:id', CustumerController.show)
router.post('/customers', CustumerController.store)
router.delete('/customers/:id', CustumerController.destroy)

module.exports = router
```

**CustumerController.js**

```
async destroy(req, res) {
  const { id } = req.params
  const result = await CustomerRepository.delete(req)
  res.json(result)
}
```

**CustomerRepository.js**

```
async destroy(id) {
  const clause = {
    where: { id }
  }

  try {
    return await Customers.destroy(clause)
  } catch (err) {
    return {
      statusCode: status.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
      message: status.classes['5XX_MESSAGE'],
      error: err
    }
  }
}
```

**example of the error in delete:**

[image]

**example of the success, in get**

[image]

I've tried, on the controller, to fire res.json () with a simple object, just for testing, but it didn't work, the request is not enough.

The problem seems to be really in the delete method of express.Router

I thank you for your help

Comment: Hi @Henrique, please take a look at [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) (do not post images of code). Also, could you add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem you are having?

Comment: Provide the `destroy` function's body.

Comment: Hi @mgarcia, thanks for the tip, i already updated my question.

Comment: @Saeed, I put the destroy function in the question

Answer (score 0):

the router is well programmed the problem has it in the endpoint response I recommend using **try catch** to analyze the error in detail

Comment: Not exactly, the problem is being routed.
I updated the question in more detail

Answer (score 0):

Everything is alright in your code, no need to change anything. debug it, first try to return **static response** on delete api instead of deleting a data from db. Then only you will get to know about the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your `get` request also should not work! You named your controller `CostumerController`  in this line:

```
const CostumerController = require('../controllers/CostumerController')
```

And used `CustumerController`. I used your code and everything works correctly.

`index.js`

```
const express = require('express');
const router = require('./router');
const app = express();

app.use(router);

app.listen(8000, () => {
  console.log('Server started.')
});
```

`CustomerController.js`

```
module.exports = {
  destroy: (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('destroy');
  },
  index: (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('index');
  },
  show: (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('show');
  },
  store: (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send('store');
  }
}
```

And `router.js`

```
const express = require('express')
const CustomerController = require('./CustomerController')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/customers', CustomerController.index)
router.get('/customers/:id', CustomerController.show)
router.post('/customers', CustomerController.store)
router.delete('/customers/:id', CustomerController.destroy)

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hi @Saeed. 
I ended up typing wrong here on Stackoverflow and getting confused with Costumer and Customer, however, according to the print above, the get method works and the post too.

In the controller, I had already used an example similar to yours, just triggering the send with a string, but the problem is that the request doesn't arrive, it doesn't call the controller